# If I just install Visual Studio 2022 desktop workload do I get a localdb instance (database instance)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

If I just install Visual Studio 2022 desktop workload do I get a database localdb instance?

For example, I'm used to being able to connect to following:

```
(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB
(localdb)\ProjectsV13
```

Can someone share some insights on how this gets added?

Comment: Have you checked the [Visual Studio workload and component IDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-and-component-ids?view=vs-2022) to see which components get installed for each workload?

Comment: perfect, if you add that as an answer i'll mark it